# Can't send a signal to a NOR chip

Tags: digital-logic

I'm a beginner and have the following circuit:

http://123d.circuits.io/circuits/201729-pulse

The left LED turns on when you plugin the battery, I'm expecting when I press the switch for the right LED to turn on, and the left LED to turn off.

The left LED should turn off as there will be input into pin 2 of the 74HC02 chip.

Pin 1 is the output

Pin 2 & 3 are inputs to the NOR gate.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, but as simple as this circuit should be, your schematic editor shows gibberish. You have a resistor tied to itself, and a switch that isn't connected on one side? Could you **please** put your circuit into a real schematic capture tool like the one built into the SE? It's got a diode symbol and a pencil symbol on it. It should be next to all the formatting buttons on the top.

Comment: That's not a circuit diagram - that's some form of cartoon version of a layout - no decoupling caps and Vcc appears to go to 9V via some form of resistor (or maybe it's an inductor?)

Comment: @horta It's a [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/projects/) drawing showing wires on a solderless breadboard.  Agree, it's pretty useless as far as understanding what the cuircuit is supposed to be.

Comment: Why was this marked with the single tag "analog".  I've changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are powering the device through a 500 ohm resistor; you left one of the inputs of the NOR gate (pin 3) unwired while pin 2 is grounded. Always grounded - regardless of the state of the switch. So no changes will happen when you push the button.

This is what I think you made:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2floOD4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can you figure out what changes you need by looking at this? It should be pretty obvious... Hint - make sure both inputs of the NOR are connected to a level, and that that level changes in a way that changes the output when the button is pressed.

You probably want to have no series resistor in the Vcc of the NOR - instead, put a series resistor in line with the LED.

And since the truth table of a NOR is

```
A  B  C
0  0  1
1  0  0
0  1  0 
1  1  0
```

you will want the unused input at ground - then the used input needs to change state when the switch is pressed, so tie it (the currently open one) to the node between the switch and the LED.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended maximum supply voltage for the 74HC02 is 7 volts - it is Not Safe to run it from 9 volts.  Either use a 7805 or similar voltage regulator to reduce the supply voltage to 5 volts, or run the circuit from a 6 volt battery pack (four AA or AAA cells).

The 510 ohm resistor won't drop the supply enough as the chip's typical power supply current is only 40 microamps, so the 510 ohm resistor may only drop the voltage by about 2 mV when the output is low, and by considerably more when the output is high, driving the LED.  With the output high, there may be enough voltage dropped in the resistor that the chip won't operate correctly.

Also, as this is a CMOS part, all unused inputs *must* be connected to ground or to Vcc, otherwise they may float to a "maybe" state, and cause the chip to try to draw exessive current.

Comment: And while Peter Bennett was not explicit enough, I will be. When he says "all unused inputs", he doesn't mean just pin 3. He means ALL unused inputs on the entire IC.

Answer (score 0):

There's some serious problems with your circuit. I'd say the biggest one right now is that one of your inputs is floating. That's usually the cause of undefined behavior, though sometimes there's an internal pull up or pull down. Don't count on it. Judging by the truth table, all you need to do is tie B to ground if you want only the one button.

As the other answerer beat me to by a mere 9 seconds, your switch never pulls up. It's always ground. You want that input on the other side of the resistor. It will be ground until the button is pressed and that node is pulled up to 1. That's also one fundamental reason why you're not seeing any changes.

There's no reason to put a resistor on a power pin, especially a 500 ohm one. Delete it.